# Borderless Winform Load Form Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

I've a Borderless Form. I overrided the CreateParams to give it an ability
for maximize and minimize from the TaskBar. When I try to Maximize the Form. The ControlBox will appear in upper-left corner of the form with the form title and disappear in a moment. This will cause a bit of flashing for that area and disturb my Form. I could not take a screenshot because it is very fast.

I tried :
Form.Text ="" and I made ControlBox=False. making MaximizeBox and MinimizeBox = False
will not solve the issue also. Still That area will flash for a moment and Close,Maximize Minimize buttons will appear for a moment.

**At least if this is cannot be resolved, I want to delay showing the form till all painting and this flash cleared.**

I'm trying to solve this issue since 2 weeks with no luck.

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        //cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        cp.Style |= 0x20000;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible this way. For example, the standard borders with the title will appear even if your form is not responsive, this is handled by the Windows. Maybe you should handle the maximizing differently. Eg. custom maximize button or menu, double-clicking the rendered custom title bar, etc.

Comment: @taffer - how to customize TaskBar button for maximize and minimize ?